# Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.Daemon: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)

Tags: 13.10, xfce, gvfs

Upon starting the xfce4 on Ubuntu 13.10, I always get the following message in the log:

```
Error creating proxy: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gtk.vfs.Daemon: Timeout was reached (g-io-error-quark, 24)

(xfsettingsd:10814): GVFS_CRITICAL **: fill_mountable_info: assertion 'proxy != NULL` failed
```

It appears about 20 seconds after the login and it also appeared on the previous version 13.04. It's a minor issue, but it's sometimes irritating because it sometimes hangs the logout, for example if I have logged in as the wrong user.

Here is the output of the `ps -ef | grep gvfs` command:

```
10821     1  0 08:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
10826     1  0 08:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//gvfsd-fuse -f /run/user/1000/gvfs
10890     1  0 08:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor
10899     1  0 08:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-monitor
10906     1  0 08:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor
10914     1  0 08:37 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor
```

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-settings/+bug/1239014). The reason was that I was using the `overlay-scrollbar` GTK module and it prevents the `xfsettingsd` from daemonizing properly.

I got the answer [here](http://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=8370).

Comment: I also have the same problem, but the answer you posted seems not work for me (13.10). In both cases I got an delay.